# ElasticSearch Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, elasticsearch, aggregate

Suppose I have documents with structure:

```
{
    name:"some_name",
    salary:INT_VAL, 
    date:YYYY.dd.MMTHH:mm:sssZ,
    num_of_months:INT_VAL 
 }
```

And now I want to make a query to elastic, that would select top 10 documents that sorted by criteria **salary*num_of_months**.
How can I do this?
And what if I want to sort by criteria with some logic inside, sth. like

```
if (num_of_months < 5) 
 then criteria = salary*100 ;
elseif  criteria = salary*200; 
endif
sort_by_criteria()
```

Comment: The best and most performant way to do it is to compute that field at indexing time and store it in the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a [Sort with a script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-request-sort.html) will enable you to perform calculations on the data and return it in the right order:

```
GET /myindex/mytype/_search?pretty
{
 "sort" :{
    "_script" : {
       "type" : "number",
        "lang": "expression",
        "script" :  "doc['num_of_months'].value <  5 ? doc['salary']*100 : doc['salary']*200",
        "order":"desc"
            }
        },
  "size": 10
}
```

Note the use of the [ternary operator](http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_0/expressions/index.html?org/apache/lucene/expressions/js/package-summary.html) to do the If statement.